# Not able to render the infoWindow in react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I was trying to add an InfoWindow to the mid point of a polyline.

This is my code for displaying the infoWindow.

```
<InfoWindow
   position={this.state.windowPosition}
   onCloseclick={this.toggleInfoWindow}
   options={{pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-30)}}
>
       <p>iggd</p>
</InfoWindow>
```

windowPosition here is the lat and lng of the midpoint of the polyline.
When I try to run this  I am getting an error saying that `You must provide either an anchor (typically render it inside a <Marker>) or a position props for <InfoWindow>`. But the owner of the repo said that  [(link's here)](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/333) we can render an infoWindow where ever we want if we pass a position as props which I am doing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What value do you get when you `console.log(this.state.windowPosition)` right before your InfoWindow component?

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
            {this.state.position && 
                 <InfoWindow position={this.state.position}>
                     <h1>My InfoWindow</h1>
                 </InfoWindow>
             }
```

This topic is discussed [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/753).